# I have problems with some Irish slang

Tags: phrases, idioms, slang

I am translating a text set in Ireland and there are some Irish phrases that I do not understand.

1- Bartley Butt-end-of-the-village: I could only find one reference in the internet. Does this mean a village idiot?

2- "Shut your face, or I'll shove down a spud down your neck!": Is this an idiom or does it literally mean shoving down a potato down someone's neck?

3- jam-jar of a cottage: What does jam-jar mean?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: #2 is definitely an idiom telling someone to be quiet. It is a very exaggerated way of saying it, so the speaker really wants to get the point across

Comment: If Bartley is a person, he might live at the extreme edge of the village?

Comment: I've also thought about it, but I only have the beginning of the story and there are only two mentions of Bartley, both suggesting that he is not quite right in the head.

Comment: For the third phrase, my guess is that it is suggesting that the cottage is as small as a jam-jar (which is the jar, usually glass, that jam comes in).

Comment: "jam-jar" sounds like another way of saying "crackerbox".

Comment: A jam-jar is not a crackerbox.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey It is when you are describing a very small house...e.g. George Harrison "Welcome to Cracker-box palace". In many parts a cracker-box house describes a very small pre-fab low-price badly-built house.

Comment: 'Butt end' is the end of a cigarette, so poor Bartley might have been discarded by the village, and become the butt of their jokes.
The spud thing probably just means blocking their voice with a potato.